# Forward email on without opening

Tags: ipad

How to forward email without opening it.  I am getting scam emails and do not want to open but forward onto report it.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable showing images in the Settings app (**Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Load Remote Images**) then the sender will have no way to tell that you looked at the email.

So, make sure you turn that on, then open the email and forward it. You can turn the option back on again when you are finished.

Comment: This does not seem to be true - I have "Automatically download pictures from the Internet" in *Preferences -> Email -> Reading* set to "Never", but when I forward the message, the messages are loaded.  Outlook version 16.16.16.

Comment: Actually - I just realized that the OP didn't specify what Application or even what OS this pertains to.  Looks like you interpreted as iOS & I thought it was Outlook on the Mac (for no good reason).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "bouncing" and this is available in certain email applications, but AFAIK, the number is few.

If you're a command line junkie (likely not) then Mutt and Alpine both have bounce capabilities.

Apparently Sylpheed/Claws also has that feature, although from memory, it's a bit difficult to locate initially.

Outlook for the Mac? Yeah, I read somewhere that it's possible, but never chased down the method.

That's as far as I can help you. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think OP is referring to bouncing, but rather 'forward on[ ]to report it'

Answer (score 0):

Once email is in your inbox it is still harmless until you open a attachment or click on a link in it.

There is a setting in Mail- preferences- composing- Responding to prevent attachments been forwarded, and only forward the selected text.

Check the "Include Selected Text..."

You basically have to select the text in the email and then use the forward.

[image: forward]